# Flex 4: htmlText property and hand cursor

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, htmltext

I need hand cursor to appear on roll over spark Label. I've tried `useHandCursor` + `buttonMode` properties, but no result. And is there anything like htmlText property for spark Label (I need underline)? Any alternative solutions are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this code suites your needs?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <s:Label buttonMode="true" horizontalCenter="0" text="Test" textDecoration="underline" verticalCenter="0" />
</s:Application>
```

If you want to have ability to mix styles together you can use the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <s:RichText buttonMode="true" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">
        <s:content>Hello, <s:span textDecoration="underline">World</s:span>!</s:content>
    </s:RichText>
</s:Application>
```

According to [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Label.html):

> The Spark architecture provides three
>   text "primitives" -- Label, RichText,
>   and RichEditableText -- as part of its
>   pay-only-for-what-you-need philosophy.
>   Label is the fastest and most
>   lightweight, but is limited in its
>   capabilities: no complex formatting,
>   no scrolling, no selection, no
>   editing, and no hyperlinks. RichText
>   and RichEditableText are built on the
>   Text Layout Framework (TLF) library,
>   rather than on FTE. RichText adds the
>   ability to render rich HTML-like text
>   with complex formatting, but is still
>   completely non-interactive.
>   RichEditableText is the slowest and
>   heaviest, but can do it all: it
>   supports scrolling with virtualized
>   TextLines, selection, editing,
>   hyperlinks, and images loaded from
>   URLs. You should use the fastest one
>   that meets your needs.

Comment: Definitely! Thanks for `textDecoration`, Konstantin. Suppose I didn't try `useHandCursor` and `buttonMode` together.

Comment: I've added a sample with mixing styles together in one single label.

Comment: And sorry for confusing using `useHandCursor`. Setting `buttonMode` to `true` is enough for hand cursor.

Comment: @Constantiner I have tried using `buttonMode` alone, but it does not seem to work. I guess we have to set even the `useHandCursor`

Comment: @Anji did you try to run code samples I posted? They work fine without `useHandCursor`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in 4.5.x.  Either with buttonMode alone, or with buttonMode and useHandCursor (or with buttonMode, useHandCursor, and mouseChildren).